# Dojo query cannot find div

Tags: javascript, dom, dojo

I am kind of new to [Dojo](https://dojo.io/) and I have a weird problem using it.

My goal is to show some search results.

So I build a store, query it and display the results by adding a new div for each result:

```
var adresseStore;
require([
         "dojo/dom", 
         "dojo/store/Memory",             
         "dojo/dom-construct",
         "dojo/query",
..
     ], 
function(dom, Memory, domConstruct, query){
  ...       
  var container = dom.byId("chefDiv")
  adresseStore = new Memory({data:data, idProperty: "myId"});
  adresseStore.query().forEach(function(item, i){
    addRow(item, container)
    // do something with the index
  }); 
...
});
```

where `addRow` basically calls `domConstruct.create("div",{...,class: "adresse",...}, container);`

and it works fine - I've got something like:

```
<div id="chefDiv">
  <div class="adresse" ...>...</div>
  <div class="adresse" ...>...</div>
</div>
```

Now, I want to open a window when someone clicks on an *"adresse"* div. To do that I have added below code:

```
 query(".adresse").on("click", function(){
     // do stuff and open a window
 }
```

and it still works fine.

Great !!! How about adding a button that will hide non-valid results? let's go:

first, add below code:

```
 query(".sltValide").on("click", function(){
   domConstruct.empty("chefDiv");
   adresseStore.query({validite:"V"}).forEach(function(item, i){
     addRow(item, container)
     // stuff with i
   }); // foreach
 }); // sltValide
```

everything displays well, I still have my

```
 <div id="chefDiv">
   <div class="adresse" ...>...</div>
   <div class="adresse" ...>...</div>
 </div>
```

with the data I want to display, I'm happy ...

... that is until I click on a div to open the window ...

the
    `query(".adresse").on("click", function(){...`
never fires because `query(".adresse")` doesn't return anything

Does anyone have a clue?

Comment: I'm actually wondering if the problem is not in the way I use the MemoryStore - maybe I should reload the page (and thus the store, making a whole new request) instead of using it as a cache ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `query()` will only contain the DOM nodes before all your nodes are dynamically created.

To fix that you should provide a query to the `on()` function (similar to how jQuery handles it), for example:

```js
query("#chefDiv").on(".adresse:click", function() {
    // Code that should be executed
});
```

Of course, you have to use a container node to query, in your case it should be `#chefDiv`. This way, dynamic nodes are also taken into account.

I also made a full example which you can see here: http://jsfiddle.net/ELSxr/

Comment: wonderful, it works perfectly
+ you solved a "dojo mystery" for me
... many many thanks :-)

Comment: It's not really a Dojo mystery though, like I said, jQuery does it the same way, in jQuery you would write it as `$("#chefDiv").on("click", ".adresse", function() { });`. It's because at the time you execute your query, the element is not known yet. However, you're binding event handlers to these elements and that's why your dynamic elements won't react to it.

Comment: you're right, and that's the point I couldn't get before your answer : I understood that I was binding the handler to not (yet) known elements, but couldn't figure out how to use a query in the `on()` function - thanx again